# Cassandra failure during read query at consistency ONE

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have a table called "securityprojections" under "commonviews" keyspace. I created indexes on two columns which i would like to query on.

The keyspace is created using:
CREATE KEYSPACE commonviews WITH replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':1};

When I run a query with filter on one column then it works fine. When i run query with filters on both indexed columns then it fails with that error:

Cassandra failure during read query at consistency ONE (One Response required but only 0 replica responded, 1 failed)

these are my queries:
works:
select * from securityprojections where position_flag = 'NONRESERVE_HOLDING' ALLOW FILTERING;

does not work:
select * from securityprojections where ticker = 'GWO CN' and position_flag = 'NONRESERVE_HOLDING' ALLOW FILTERING;

Any idea what may causing this?

Comment: It sounds like you might have a multinode cluster with one or more nodes down. With RF=1 you can lose availability with only one node out. Have you checked `nodetool status`?